# MySQL transaction rollback in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions

I am facing a weird problem. I am using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) for connecting to MySQL DB from NodeJS. Below is the connection pool that I am creating.

```
mysql.createPool({
        host     : connectDB.mysql.hostname,
        user     : connectDB.mysql.username,
        password : connectDB.mysql.password,
        connectionLimit : connectDB.connectionLimit
});
```

I am trying to use transaction and to begin the transaction using the method [beginTransaction](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#transactions)

My requirement is to dynamically create database and tables. Sample query for creating database and table is mentioned below that I am doing.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8; //Create the database

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`test_table` (
  `test_table_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_table_key` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `test_table_value` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_table_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `test_table_id_UNIQUE` (`test_table_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COMMENT = 'Test table.'
```

The problem here is when I try to rollback the transaction the database and the tables created are not getting rollback. To rollback I am using the transaction rollback method using the same transaction connection.

```
connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check: [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

Comment: Thanks...looks like I will not be able to rollback in case of any failure.

Comment: At least not automatically.